# Radiobutton only works on one form and other form can not

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, forms, radio-button

I am trying to modify the input style of the input type radio and I have the radio input in two different forms. but the radio input only works on the first form only while the second does not. I am still confused by the problem why not work on the second.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

ex : https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/vaqdsmjk/10/

```
<input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="oneway" value="oneway" checked="">
<label for="oneway">Oneway</label>
```

```css
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #F87DA9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="flights">
  <form name="flight" method="GET" action="" id="searchFlights" class="form-inline">
    <ul class="radio-list">
      <li id="radioFlights">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="oneway" value="oneway" checked="">
        <label for="oneway">Oneway</label>
      </li>
      <li id="radioFlights">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="return" value="return">
        <label for="return">Return</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="trains">
  <form name="train" method="GET" action="" id="searchTrains" class="form-inline">
    <ul class="radio-list">
      <li id="radioTrains">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="oneway" value="oneway" checked="">
        <label for="oneway">Oneway</label>
      </li>
      <li id="radioTrains">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="return" value="return">
        <label for="return">Return</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You have several elements using the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Id` must be unique. So please give unique `id` in radio input.

```css
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #F87DA9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="flights">
  <form name="flight" method="GET" action="" id="searchFlights" class="form-inline">
    <ul class="radio-list">
      <li id="radioFlights">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="oneway" value="oneway" checked="">
        <label for="oneway">Oneway</label>
      </li>
      <li id="radioFlights">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="return" value="return">
        <label for="return">Return</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="trains">
  <form name="train" method="GET" action="" id="searchTrains" class="form-inline">
    <ul class="radio-list">
      <li id="radioTrains">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="oneway2" value="oneway" checked="">
        <label for="oneway2">Oneway</label>
      </li>
      <li id="radioTrains">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtrip" id="return2" value="return">
        <label for="return2">Return</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you would like the first two radios in You need to set different the "searchFlights" form to work together and the other two in "searchTrain" form to work together.

If that is the case, you would need different names for the radio inputs in each form. Radios work by matching the "name" part of the input.

You could try changing each set to use a different name. For example, using "roundtripFlight"  for "searchFlights" form and "roundtripTrain" for "searchTrains" form.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="flights">
  <form name="flight" method="GET" action="" id="searchFlights" class="form-inline">
    <ul class="radio-list">
      <li id="radioFlights">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtripFlight" id="oneway" value="oneway" checked="">
        <label for="oneway">Oneway</label>
      </li>
      <li id="radioFlights">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtripFlight" id="return" value="return">
        <label for="return">Return</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="trains">
  <form name="train" method="GET" action="" id="searchTrains" class="form-inline">
    <ul class="radio-list">
      <li id="radioTrains">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtripTrain" id="oneway" value="oneway" checked="">
        <label for="oneway">Oneway</label>
      </li>
      <li id="radioTrains">
        <input type="radio" name="roundtripTrain" id="return" value="return">
        <label for="return">Return</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```